# How to delay nth child item animation in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-animations, settimeout

I want delay animation for another item's directly by Vue Js, not css.

In this moment Vue wait until all items has rendered, and all appear at the same time.
How to do delay by change `this.animated = true` ?

*Item.vue*

```
<template>
    <transition name="animation-fade">
      <div v-if="this.animated">
        {{this.itemProp.content}}   
      </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'Item',
    props: {
      itemProp: Object,
    },
      data: function() {
        return {
          animated: false,
          loading: true,
        };
      }, 

      methods: {
        delayedShow: function(delay) {
          setTimeout(this.toggleItem, delay) 
        },
      },
      toggleItem: function() {
        this.animated = true;
      },
      mounted: function() {
        this.delayedShow(500);
      },
    }
    
</script>
```

Items are defined in other component and every pass by prop to Item model.

Help me please.

Comment: Have you tried using `transition-delay`? https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9385#issuecomment-494931321

Comment: @Kunkun, Thanks, I tired, but it isn't solve delay another item. Still all items are delayed.

Comment: It seems the code does not reflect items but only a single item. Is staggered animation wanted? Vue seems to have docs on how to handle misc transitions https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions